# Seemingly Irreversible Custom Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, keyboard

I have a late 2010 Apple MacBook (If that matters) and when I had OS X Snow Leopard installed, I created a keyboard shortcut that I seemingly can no longer reverse.  After upgrading to OS X Lion and now OS X Mountain Lion the shortcut is still carried over.

The keyboard shortcut is: whenever I click the 'fn' key, it will 'show desktop.'

I have searched all of the 'Keyboard' section of System Preferences to see if I can deactivate anything there.

I do remember that when I made the shortcut originally on Snow Leopard, it could be changed back.

I remember when I had OS X Lion, I wanted to change it, but I couldn't figure out how (like now)

I have tried the 'restore defualt' option in System Preferences > Keyboard, but that didn't work.

If anyone knows how to fix this or even has some sort of guidance to help me try and fix it, it would be greatly appreciated as this is becoming an increasingly inconvenient and frustrating problem.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question entitled **"Fn key shows the desktop on my Mac"** was posted in July 2012 on Superuser, and maybe of help.

https://superuser.com/questions/455603/fn-key-shows-the-desktop-on-my-mac

(If my answer is more appropriate as a comment, please convert it to one)

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the Mission Control preferences? There's still an option to assign fn to showing the desktop on 10.8.

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me nuts too but I managed to find a fix for it.

Go to **System Preferences / Keyboard** and reset everything to default. ( I am not sure if this is absolutely necessary, though). I also *unticked* everything to do with *Mission Control*.

Go to **System Preferences / Mission Control** and *untick* **all** the options and change the keyboard shortcuts all to '-'.

After closing **System Preferences** <kbd>Fn</kbd> should no longer shows the Desktop!

I think it must have been a hangover from when I upgraded to 10.8 from 10.6.